# Unable to delete a model -- function Ecto.Query.__changeset__/0 is undefined or private

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to delete an item and all its children:

```
where(ParentModel, [x], x.user_id == 123)
|> first
|> Repo.delete()

# or
# Repo.delete(where(ParentModel, [x], x.user_id == 123))
```

Both throw an exception:

```
function Ecto.Query.__changeset__/0 is undefined or private
```

What does it have to do with validation?

In the parent model I have `on_delete: :delete_all`

Answer (score 7):

Replace `first()` with either [`Repo.one!()`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:one!/2) or [`Repo.delete_all()`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:delete_all/2). `Ecto.Query.first()` returns a query, but `Repo.delete()` requires either a struct of the model or a changeset. If you pass it a query, it just gets confused.

By using `Repo.one!()`, you first fetch the struct, then pass it to `Repo.delete()`, which `Repo.delete()` can work with.

`Repo.delete_all()` can take a query, but it will straight up delete anything that matches the query. So be careful.